# Dictionary<string, object> to DataTable

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a very strange issue, and no clue which way I should take to fix it.

I have an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>` and it can contain one or more `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>`.

Now, this Dictionary needs to be imported into DataTable, and if the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>` inside has 0 children, then the DataTable should contain only one row with the Column names as strings, and the RowData as objects (string in this case). But, if there is a child, then the DataTable should contains the same number of rows as this child, and other information in every row from parent.

For instance, the parent Dictionary has these values:

```
string, object
---------------
Name, Mike
LastName, Tyson
```

IEnumerable dictionary child has:

```
string, object
----------------
[0]
ChildName, John
ChildAge, 10

[1]
ChildName, Tony
ChildAge, 12
```

Result should be:

```
Name    LastName     ChildName     ChildAge
--------------------------------------------
Mike    Tyson        John          10
Mike    Tyson        Tony          12
```

Also, Parent IEnumerable can have many children IEnumerable, but they will all have the same size.

Does anyone have idea how to solve this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var child1 = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    var childOneDic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "ChildName", "John" }, 
        { "ChildAge", 10 } 
    };
    child1.Add(childOneDic);

    var child2 = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    var childTwoDic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "ChildName", "Tony" }, 
        { "ChildAge", 12 } 
    };
    child2.Add(childTwoDic);
    
    var parent = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    var parentDic = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Mike" },
        { "LastName", "Tyson" },
        { "child1", child1 },
        { "child2", child2 }
    };
    parent.Add(parentDic);

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("LastName");
    table.Columns.Add("ChildName");
    table.Columns.Add("ChildAge");
    table = CreateTable(parent, null, table);
}

static DataTable CreateTable(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> parent, 
                             DataRow row, DataTable table)
{
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
    }

    foreach (var v in parent)
    {
        foreach (var o in v)
        {
            if (o.Value.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                var dic = (IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>) o.Value;
                CreateTable(dic, row, table);
            }
            else
            {
                row[o.Key] = o.Value;
            }
        }

        if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
        {
            DataRow tempRow = table.NewRow();
            tempRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
            table.Rows.Add(tempRow);
        }
        else
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Once you solve this for one-level, wouldn't it work recursively?  (assuming your stack doesn't blow up)

Comment: This doesn't look that hard. looks doable. What you tried so far? If you are struck somewhere we'll help you.

Comment: I've made recursion and it works file if i have one child... But i am getting issue when i get two childs

Comment: @GoranZadro post that code where you have issues. It's much easier to help that way..

Comment: Better yet create actual data for us to try our hand with.

Comment: I've put some code which i remember - worked on this for like 6 hours today and just went outside. Now i am thinking again about it. I guess I am still in recursive function :D
BTW: code didn't looked exactly like this - this is just from my head right now

Comment: @GoranZadro oh my... I stopped at seeing the `parrentDic` variable. Seriously why is that so? Huge design smell.. :(

Comment: This is the way i am getting data - can't do anything about it and easiest way for me to manipulate with data later is with DataTable. That's why I am trying to create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq is a good candidate for this job. I still think you should rethink about design, this is such a horrible thing to do. This should do (and without any hard coding):

```
var child1 = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ChildName", "John" }, { "ChildAge", 10 } }
};

var child2 = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ChildName", "Tony" }, { "ChildAge", 12 } }
};

var parent = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "Name", "Mike" },
        { "LastName", "Tyson" },
        { "child1", child1 },
        { "child2", child2 }
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Lykke" },
        { "LastName", "Li" },
        { "child1", child1 },
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    { 
        { "Name", "Mike" },
        { "LastName", "Oldfield" }
    }
};

CreateTable(parent);

static DataTable CreateTable(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> parents)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        var children = parent.Values
                             .OfType<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>()
                             .ToArray();

        var length = children.Any() ? children.Length : 1;

        var parentEntries = parent.Where(x => x.Value is string)
                                  .Repeat(length)
                                  .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        var childEntries = children.SelectMany(x => x.First())
                                   .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        var allEntries = parentEntries.Concat(childEntries)
                                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());

        var headers = allEntries.Select(x => x.Key)
                                .Except(table.Columns
                                             .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName))
                                .Select(x => new DataColumn(x))
                                .ToArray();
        table.Columns.AddRange(headers);

        var addedRows = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            addedRows[i] = table.Rows.IndexOf(table.Rows.Add());

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            object[] columnRows;
            if (!allEntries.TryGetValue(col.ColumnName, out columnRows))
                continue;

            for (int i = 0; i < addedRows.Length; i++)
                table.Rows[addedRows[i]][col] = columnRows[i];
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

This is one extension method I've used:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int times)
{
    source = source.ToArray();
    return Enumerable.Range(0, times).SelectMany(_ => source);
}
```

You can create the `addedRows` variable in a more *idiomatic* fashion (which I prefer) but may be that's little less readable for others. In a single line, like this:

```
var addedRows = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                          .Select(x => new
                          {
                              relativeIndex = x,
                              actualIndex = table.Rows.IndexOf(table.Rows.Add())
                          })
                          .ToArray();
```

The tricky part here is to get the pivoting right. No big deal in our case since we can utilize indexers. Do test with a set of examples and let me know if this is buggy..

---

One another way of doing it is to precalculate the headers (data table columns before the  loop) as it's not going to change anyway. But that also means one extra round of enumeration. As to which is more efficient, you will have to test it.. I find the first one more elegant though.

```
static DataTable CreateTable(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> parents)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    //excuse the meaningless variable names

    var c = parents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Values
                                         .OfType<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>()
                                         .Any());
    var p = c ?? parents.FirstOrDefault();
    if (p == null)
        return table;

    var headers = p.Where(x => x.Value is string)
                   .Select(x => x.Key)
                   .Concat(c == null ? 
                           Enumerable.Empty<string>() : 
                           c.Values
                            .OfType<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>()
                            .First()
                            .SelectMany(x => x.Keys))
                   .Select(x => new DataColumn(x))
                   .ToArray();
    table.Columns.AddRange(headers);

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        var children = parent.Values
                             .OfType<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>()
                             .ToArray();

        var length = children.Any() ? children.Length : 1;

        var parentEntries = parent.Where(x => x.Value is string)
                                  .Repeat(length)
                                  .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        var childEntries = children.SelectMany(x => x.First())
                                   .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        var allEntries = parentEntries.Concat(childEntries)
                                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());

        var addedRows = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                                  .Select(x => new
                                  {
                                      relativeIndex = x,
                                      actualIndex = table.Rows.IndexOf(table.Rows.Add())
                                  })
                                  .ToArray();

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            object[] columnRows;
            if (!allEntries.TryGetValue(col.ColumnName, out columnRows))
                continue;

            foreach (var row in addedRows)
                table.Rows[row.actualIndex][col] = columnRows[row.relativeIndex];
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty good but there is an issue - if parrent have more than one Dictionary then only first will be translated. I've updated example code to include all cases and result now should have 4 rows, two for Mike Tyson, one for Lykke Li and one for Mike Oldfield with empty values for child column names. I can probably foreach them before calling CreateTable and then load all temp datatables in one big, but i guess that there is a way to handle this in better way

Comment: @GoranZadro Ok I will update my answer, should be straightforward. Just that you have to suitably add column headers.

Comment: @GoranZadro is "Name" and "LastName" guaranteed to be in parent dictionaries?

Comment: Actually not, it can be anything

Comment: @GoranZadro, no, what I'm asking is would it be guaranteed that a pair of values (in your case "Name" and "LastName") to be present in all the parent dictionaries? Ok, anyway I'll write my answer. You see if it fits your data. Can't imagine all the possible scenarios.

Comment: Yes, they will and this is working perfectly! Dude, you rock! Thank you very much for this - it is truly great piece of work!

Comment: @GoranZadro :) Glad it helped. Understanding how it works is very important, when you have to debug or fix bugs.. Hope the idea is clear. I really dont want it to be as shopping code... Linq is pretty easy, and quite fun. More importantly it helps in situations like this (which otherwise would have been a nightmare). And do not forget to refactor code into nice little methods!

Comment: "var parentEntries = parent.Where(x => x.Value is string).Repeat(length)".
The .Repeat doesn't exist...

Comment: @sLowDowN repeat is an extension method I defined myself. See the repeat function I wrote. Put it in some static public class.

Comment: Ah, I somehow didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use classes, that way it will be easier to see and manipulate the data. Here's an example of what you can do based on the example you gave. The trick is also to keep a reference of the parent inside the child. That you just need to pass the list of child to the grid.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var child1 = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var childOneDic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { "ChildName", "John" }, 
    { "ChildAge", 10 } 
};
        child1.Add(childOneDic);

        var child2 = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var childTwoDic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { "ChildName", "Tony" }, 
    { "ChildAge", 12 } 
};
        child2.Add(childTwoDic);

        var parrent = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var parrentDic = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Name", "Mike" },
    { "LastName", "Tyson" },
    { "child1", child1 },
    { "child2", child2 }
};
        parrent.Add(parrentDic);


        List<Parent> goodList = new List<Parent>();
        List<Child> allChilds = new List<Child>();

        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> p in parrent)
        {
            Parent newParent = new Parent(p);

            goodList.Add(newParent);
            allChilds.AddRange(newParent.Childs);
        }

        foreach (Child c in allChilds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.ParentName + ":" + c.ParentName + ":" + c.Name + ":" + c.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public class Parent
    {
        private List<Child> _childs = new List<Child>();

        private Dictionary<string, object> _dto;

        public Parent(Dictionary<string, object> dto)
        {
            _dto = dto;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            {
                if (_dto.ContainsKey("child" + i))
                {
                    _childs.Add(new Child(((List<Dictionary<string, object>>)_dto["child" + i])[0], this));
                }
            }

        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)_dto["Name"]; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return (string)_dto["LastName"]; }
        }

        public List<Child> Childs
        {
            get { return _childs; }

        }

    }

    public class Child
    {

        private Parent _parent;

        private Dictionary<string, object> _dto;

        public Child(Dictionary<string, object> dto, Parent parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            _dto = dto;

        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)_dto["ChildName"]; }
        }


        public int Age
        {
            get { return (int)_dto["ChildAge"]; }
        }

        public string ParentName
        {
            get { return _parent.Name; }
        }

        public string ParentLastName
        {
            get { return _parent.LastName; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do this without being stuck on same problem. Also, I don't think that it is possible to use class because i need very generic approach which can handle up to n childs (or none) and yes, they (can) have different properties.

Comment: @GoranZadro I changed my awnser to represent the example you have

Comment: Just one more question - I can't understand what:

Comment: Just one more question - I can't understand what
_childs.Add(new Child(_dto["child" + i](0), this));
line is doing. 
Build error pop-up, so i've changed it to _childs.Add(new Child(_dto, this)); - not sure is this what is expected?

Comment: @GoranZadro sorry about that, I made the proper change, it should work now. I converted it from vb.net without testing it.

Comment: Looking good but when i have parrent with no child i get results only from parrent object with children.  I've updated example code to include all cases and result now should have 4 rows, two for Mike Tyson, one for Lykke Li and one for Mike Oldfield with empty values for child column names.