# Populate ASP.Net DropDownList with JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dictionary

How to get certain values from json string, and insert it into a dictionary in C# ?

The following is my json string:

```
[{"RowNum":7,"Item_Code":"m2","Item_Name":"Mixer","Item_ProductBrand":0,"Item_Category":1,"Item_Unit":0,"Item_Blocked":false,"Costing_Method":0,"Standard_Cost":0.0,"Retail_UnitPrice":10.0,"Dealer_UnitPrice":20.0,"Distributor_UnitPrice":30.0,"Safety_Stock":0.0,"Safety_LeadTime":0,"Reorder_Point":0.0,"Reorder_Quantity":0.0,"BusinessUnitID":"1","CompanyID":"1","RowVersion":1},{"RowNum":8,"Item_Code":"t1","Item_Name":"Television","Item_ProductBrand":0,"Item_Category":1,"Item_Unit":0,"Item_Blocked":false,"Costing_Method":0,"Standard_Cost":0.0,"Retail_UnitPrice":40.0,"Dealer_UnitPrice":50.0,"Distributor_UnitPrice":60.0,"Safety_Stock":0.0,"Safety_LeadTime":0,"Reorder_Point":0.0,"Reorder_Quantity":0.0,"BusinessUnitID":"1","CompanyID":"1","RowVersion":1}]
```

Currently I have two json objects in this string. It is actually a string created in the form of JSON Array.

I have a Dictionary, into which I need to add Item_Name and Item_Code. How to do that?

I was successful in creating the Dictionary and adding/mapping elements from the string. But, I cannot populate the DropDownList. My code is :

```
string items = GetJSON(url);
Dictionary<string, string>[] itemDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(items);
DropDownList3.DataSource = itemDictionary;
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "Item_Name";
DropDownList3.DataValueField = "Item_Code";
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

This is not working. How to correct this ?

Comment: Convert it to Table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923005/dictionarystring-object-to-datatable

Answer (score 2):

you should create a list, you shouldn't bind the dictionary to combobox,  I don't think you even can. May be I am wrong but it is not the clean way. So what you can do is to create a list of objects, and from the dictionary create an object, for example Item object similar to what I wrote below, then add the object to the list.And finally set the list as the data source. That will work. something like this:

```
public class item
{
    public Customer(){
    }

    public int ItemCode{set; get;}
    public string ItemName{set; get;} 

   // and the other properties 

}
```

then from the dictonary create the object and add it to the list.

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
string items = GetJSON(url);
Dictionary<string, string>[] itemDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(items);
Item newItem = new Item();
newmItem.ItemCode = Convert.ToInt32 (itemDictionary["Item_Code"]); 
// ... and the other properties 
// then add the object to the list 
itemList.Add(newItem);
DropDownList3.DataSource = itemList;
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "ItemName";

DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

Then bind it to index_changed event and from there cast it to Item object and get the property that you are interested