# Converting Stored Procedure PIVOT table to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

My idea was to convert the currently stored procedure what I've defined before. The intention is, that I can't return the data from the database with the stored procedure. The reasons for this purpose was leaving in the query. I need to convert an existing table to a pivot table and after that I have to return the data via ASP.NET WebAPI. This pivot table is dynamically that means when the user adds a new article then it will be added in the pivot table as a column.

The normal table looks like as follows:

```
datum      | rate     | article
--------------------------------
2013-01-03 |  97,766..|  DE011
2013-01-05 |  90.214..|  DE090
2013-01-10 |  97,890..|  DE011
2013-01-13 |  65,023..|  DE220
2013-01-13 |  97,012..|  DE300
2013-01-15 |  97,344..|  DE300
....
```

the pivot table should looks like as follows:

```
rate | DE011 | ... | DE090 | ... | DE220 | ... | DE300
-------------------------------------------------------
100  |   0   | ... |   1   | ... |   0   | ... |   0
 98  |   2   | ... |   0   | ... |   1   | ... |   0
 97  |   0   | ... |   0   | ... |   0   | ... |   2
 90  |   0   | ... |   1   | ... |   0   | ... |   4
...
```

the column `datum` is important for the pivot table because the user have to take some input in the angular view.. in this example the user is choosing `dateFrom` and `dateTo` inputs. The rate will round the numbers how you can see in the pivot column `rate`.The article descriptions are in the new table column titles and the rate will count for each article.

My stored procedure works fine in SQL Server. But after the SP was imported to the EDM Model the Entity Framework defined a return type `INT` and that is impossible for my purposes.

Here is the code of EF:

```
 public virtual int getMonthIsin(Nullable<System.DateTime> fromDate, Nullable<System.DateTime> toDate)
        {
            var fromDateParameter = fromDate.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("fromDate", fromDate) :
                new ObjectParameter("fromDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

            var toDateParameter = toDate.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("toDate", toDate) :
                new ObjectParameter("toDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("getMonthIsin", fromDateParameter, toDateParameter);
        }
```

I also have tried the .SqlQuery() in my WebAPI-Controller as follows:

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<IQueryable>("EXEC getMonthIsin @fromDate, @toDate", fromDate, toDate).AsQueryable();
```

But it doesn't work.

Well, now the idea is to try a LINQ query and get the return values. I don't have any idea to implement this :(

Currently I've tried approximately this LINQ query:

```
public IQueryable getDatas(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
   var query = from t in db.table1
               where t.datum >= fromDate && t.datum <= toDate
               group t by t.article
                 into grp
                 select new
                 {
                    articles = grp.Key,
                    rate = grp.Select(g => g.rate),
                    total = grp.Select(g => g.rate).AsQueryable()
                 };

   return query;
}
```

But this isn't really the correct return. It would be very helpful when anyone can help me!! I will upvoted each good answer!

Comment: You'll never be able to capture the output of a dynamic PIVOT statement into a static EF type. Use something like Dapper.

Comment: @GertArnold Do you have any examples to see them? How can I define it with LINQ?

Comment: @GertArnold Do you know how to realize the pivot example above with Dapper Dot Net?

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy Do you have an idea for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is not suitable for fetching dynamic data structures. [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) is the tool to use here. It basically is a collection of extension methods on `IDbConnection`, one of which is `Query` that returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, where `dynamic` is an object that implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. Getting the data is really simple:

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> result;

using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add(" @fromDate", fromDate, DbType.DateTime);
    p.Add(" @toDate", toDate, DbType.DateTime);

    result = (IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>)
                cnn.Query(sql: "getMonthIsin", 
                          param: p, 
                          commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Now you have an `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` in which one item (`IDictionary<string, object>`) represents one row of key/value pairs from the stored procedure's result set:

```
Key    Value
-----  ----
rate   100
DE011  0
...    ...
DE090  1
...    ...
DE220  0
...    ...
DE300  0
```

It's up to you how to go from here. You could, for instance, convert the result to a `DataTable` as shown here: [Dictionary<string, object> to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18923005/861716).

By the way, Dapper isn't only simple, it's blazingly fast too.

Comment: Where I have to add the code above? Do I need the `using` statement because my connection is in Controller defined as follows: `private TestContext db = new TestContext();` and in the Context.cs who was generated from EF  are defined all connections to the stored procedures `public partial class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("name=TestContext")
        {
        }...`

Comment: You can do this without any reference to EF. Just grab the connection string from your config file and create your own SqlConnection instance.

Comment: That means I can add the code in the controller directly?

Comment: To access the Stored Procedure from the client-side I'm using the Controller `public class QR_DS022Controller : ApiController
    {...}` with all GET-Requests. In this Controller I can't define using(...) and so on. Sorry for the stupid question but do you have an idea how I can do define your example in the controller to accessing the query from my client?

Comment: OK, let's make a separation here. I suggest you try this code outside of your project and see if it suits you. If so, let's close this question, and then you continue asking a new question about where to integrate this code in your project. I need more specific details to be able to judge that. For instance, I don't see why you can't do this in a controller (apart from the question whether you *should* do it there).

Comment: One thing: you shouldn't put this code in your context. Create a service class.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and give you an inform.

Comment: I've solved my problem with your example! veryyyyyy nice!